# Using getElementById in Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building a project on Ionic, with the use of BackendLess. But I cannot seem to use the id of HTML elements in the typescript file.

I have made use of @ViewChild in the code.

HTML Code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" id="name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" id="email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="password" id="password"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Phone Number</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" id="phone"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Profile Picture</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="file" id="pic"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

```
<button ion-button (click)='userreg();'>Register</button></ion-content>
```

Typescript Code:

```
export class Register {

  @ViewChild('name') name;
  @ViewChild('email') email;
  @ViewChild('password') password;
  @ViewChild('phone') phone;
  @ViewChild('pic') pic;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
   }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad Register');
  }

   userreg() {
  var picURL;
  var user = new Backendless.User();
      user.email=this.email;
      user.password=this.password;
      user.name=this.name;
      user.phone=this.phone;

  Backendless.UserService.register( user ).then( this.userRegistered ).catch( this.gotError );
}

gotError( err ) // see more on error handling
    {
  console.log( "error message - " + err.message );
      console.log( "error code - " + err.statusCode );
    }

userRegistered( user )
    {
  console.log("User registered");
}

}
```

The @ViewChild does not seem to be getting the values. i checked the output on the console, and it shows 'Undefined' as the output, therefore not allowing registration into BackendLess.

Comment: Don't post link to external sources. As they might go offline, and future user cannot access them. Instead just paste the relevant piece(s) inside your question.

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild("some-string")` doesn't fetch the element with the id `some-string` but instead the template reference `some-string`. You can give your HTML elements a template reference like this:

`<ion-input type="email" #email></ion-input>`

And then use this to get the template reference:

`@ViewChild("email") email: ElementRef;`

Note that `ElementRef` is the type you get. `ElementRef` has one property called `nativeElement` which is the actual `HTMLElement` (in this case `HTMLInputElement`).

**Important remark:**

Since you want to get the value of the HTMLElements and not really their reference, data binding would be the much better approach. Here is how it works:

*HTML:*

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

And then you just have to define a property `name` in your component:

```
public name: string;
```

Angular now sets the value automatically for you.

Comment: So in this case, how would I make use of ElementRef to obtain the value of the input provided by the user?

Comment: `email.nativeElement.ANY_HTML_PROPERTY` so in this case `email.nativeElement.value`.

Comment: However I don't suggest you reading the value like this. Ever heard about data-binding? Check it out and try to use it.

Comment: Getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: I edited the answer. You should try to use data binding instead of html references. It's never a good idea in angular to access the DOM directly.

Comment: I am unsure about where to place the `name` property you spoke about.

Comment: Just where you define your component properties. At the same place you defined `@ViewChild("email") email;` :D

Comment: How would data binding be used for pictures? I changed the last item on the list to `[(ng-model)]="pic"`, and added a property `public pic: any;`. It returns `undefined`.

Comment: `[(ngModel)]` is a two way databinding. Meaning it handles out- and input. Since you your pic tag has no input, you have to use output binding. Like this. `[id]="pic"`. This changed `id` as soon as `pic`changes. Please inform yourself about databinding.